# Persist array from before_save callback for ActiveModel::Dirty like change tracking on has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, memcached

Firstly, apologies for the snappy question title! It does however sum up what I am trying to do.

I've been using [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) successfully to create a kind of audit trail on various model attributes within my app (like on Product below).

I've now have a fairly pressing request to be able to track the changes (additions  & deletions in this case) on an associated has_many through relationship.

The models in question are:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products_territories, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :territories, :through => :products_territories
end

class Territory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products_territories
  has_many :products, :through => :products_territories
end

class ProductsTerritory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :territory
    belongs_to :product
end
```

I've failed with using ActiveModel::Dirty, it doesn't seem possible, so am trying my own thing which on the surface is quite simple; grab an array of a product's products_territories before_save and then again after_save and then perform comparisons on the two arrays to identify the additions and deletions. What I can't get my head around is the best way to persist the array of products_territories from the before save so it's then available to my after_save callback. I'm pretty certain @@ class variables aren't the way to go and i'm also not so sure about session variables. I'm wondering whether something like Redis or Memchached is what I should be looking at?

Can anyone that's had to do something similar to this give me any pointers or direct me to some further reading please?

Thanks in advance.